# How can I disable logging for quarkus-kubernetes-config?

Tags: java, quarkus

We're using the quarkus quarkubernetes-config extension to integrate with our kubernetes configmaps. We noticed that upon app startup, the contents of our configmap will get printed to the console by this extension, and these contents also include our secrets.

To prevent our secrets from being printed to the console, what settings would we need to adjust? The logs are coming through in this format:

[image]

And to try and disable this behavior, I tried setting the following in our quarkus config, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I figured setting this to warn instead of info would do the trick, but that doesn't appear to be the case:

```
  log:
category:
  "okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform":
    level: WARN
console:
  json: false
color: false
```

EDIT: adding full yaml config minus the logging lines

```
quarkus:
  application:
    name: myservice
  kubernetes-config:
    enabled: true
    config-maps: myservice
    secrets:
      ~: my-credentials
      enabled: true
  smallrye-graphql:
    ui:
      enable: true
      always-include: true
    show-runtime-exception-message: io.quarkus.security.ForbiddenException
  swagger-ui:
    always-include: true
  pagination:
    defaultPageNumber: 1
    defaultPageSize: 1000
```

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using? OkHTTP has not been used in quarkus-kubernetes-config for a while now...

Comment: @geoand this is on 2.9.2

Comment: Okay, my bad, please disregard the comment above as I was thinking of something else.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue at all... Can you post your entire `application.yaml`?

Comment: @geoand sure, I just updated my post with it now. I've left out the logging configuration lines since they weren't doing anything

Comment: @geoand after looking into this some more, it appears that it does not log like this when running locally in my dev environment but when I compile the app and run it in kubernetes it'll suddenly start showing those log messages. I had tested locally against a kubernetes testing env and did not see any such log lines. Do you know what could cause that kind of behavior?

Comment: Not really unfortunately

Comment: @geoand ok, no problem. is it possible that another extension could be interfering with the logging level for everything? I noticed too that when enabling open tracing, everything will work fine when running locally in dev mode, but the tracing logs don't show anymore when running in k8. Either way though I've just decided to use the kubernetes config extension for just the config for now and have switched to pulling the secrets directly from vault instead. Thanks again for your help with this